# How to approach problem

Tags: probability, distributions

I have a discrete random variable f(phi) with known probabilities for each n outcomes. Phi represents the random variables m parameters. Each parameter is its own independent discrete random variable with known probabilities for each outcome. Would it be possible to construct a distribution for f(phi) based on the values of its parameters? If so how would I go about that. I have a intermediate understanding of statistics, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to think about something like this.

Basically, I want to generate values for phi and input them into f() to see the predicted value of the random variable.

Let me know if/how I am off base, I am trying to learn more about stats and probability and thought this might be a good place to ask questions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what phi and m are? Maybe some context?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  You should change your title to something that says something about your problem.  Also, what does " Phi represents the random variables m parameters." mean?

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, this scenario involves creating a distribution for a function of several independent discrete random variables. Here is one approach to achieve this:

1. Know Each Parameter’s Distribution: Suppose $\phi$ consists of parameters $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, ..., $\phi_m$, where each $\phi_i$ is an independent discrete random variable with a known probability distribution. The probability distribution for each $\phi_i$ is given by $P(\phi_i = x)$ for all possible outcomes $x$.
2. Define the Function $f(\phi)$: The function $f$ should be clearly defined in terms of its operation on the parameters $\phi$.
3. Construct Joint Distribution: If the parameters $\phi_i$ are independent, the joint distribution of all parameters is the product of their individual distributions. However, if $f$ operates on these parameters separately, you may not need to compute the full joint distribution.
4. Apply the Function $f$ to Each Outcome: For each combination of outcomes of the parameters $\phi$, you compute the value of $f(\phi)$. This step involves calculating $f(\phi)$ for every possible combination of $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, ..., $\phi_m$.
5. Calculate the Probability for Each Value of $f(\phi)$: You need to find the probability of each value that $f(\phi)$ can take. This involves summing up the probabilities of all combinations of $\phi$ that result in the same value of $f(\phi)$.
6. Construct the Distribution for $f(\phi)$: With the set of possible values of $f(\phi)$ and their corresponding probabilities, you can construct the probability mass function (PMF) for $f(\phi)$.

For example, if $\phi$ has two parameters $X$ and $Y$, and $X$ can take values {1, 2} with probabilities {0.3, 0.7} and $Y$ can take values {3, 4} with probabilities {0.6, 0.4}. Define a function $f(\phi) = f(X, Y) = X + Y$.

To find the distribution of $f(\phi)$, you would:

List all combinations of $X$ and $Y$: (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4).
Calculate $f(\phi)$ for each combination: 4, 5, 5, 6.
Calculate the probability for each value of $f(\phi)$:
$$P(f(\phi) = 4) = P(X=1) \times P(Y=3) = 0.3 \times 0.6 = 0.18$$.
$$P(f(\phi) = 5) = P(X=1) \times P(Y=4) + P(X=2) \times P(Y=3) = 0.3 \times 0.4 + 0.7 \times 0.6 = 0.54$$.
$$P(f(\phi) = 6) = P(X=2) \times P(Y=4) = 0.7 \times 0.4 = 0.28$$

The PMF for $f(\phi)$ can then be constructed using these probabilities. For complex functions or a large number of parameters, computational methods like Monte Carlo simulations may be employed to approximate the distribution.